# How to catch arbitrary exception in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, exception, ghc

How to catch exceptions in Haskell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have figured it out after reading this paper: [An Extensible Dynamically-Typed Hierarchy of Exceptions](http://www.haskell.org/~simonmar/papers/ext-exceptions.pdf)

```
handle (\(SomeException e) -> return $ "caught: " ++ show e) undefined
```